# Checking video integrity using ffmpeg with Python

Tags: python-2.7, ffmpeg

I am trying to check video integrity and made it successfully using mac terminal with the line of code below:

```
ffmpeg -v error -i filename.mp4 -f null - 2>error.log
```

Now i am trying to do the same in python with no success making the cmd command. I try to do:

```
cmds = ["ffmpeg", "-i","filename.mp4", "-v", "error", "-f", "null", "-", "2>", "error.log"]
subprocess.Popen(cmds)
```

But i am getting the error - `2>: Invalid argument`
I also tried also `"2>error.log"` instead of `"2>", "error.log"` but then im getting `2>error.log: Invalid argument`

Comment: I am not a python user, but your script is missing the `-`, as in `-f null -`.

Comment: i added it but there is no change with the error

Comment: Possible lazy solution is to use `["ffmpeg", "-v", "error", "-i","filename.mp4", "-f", "null", "-"]`, then `python script 2> error.log`.

Answer (score 2):

I found a work around to fix the problem.
I am running the command with python from the terminal using:

```
import os

os.system("ffmpeg -v error -i filename.mp4 -f null - 2>error.log")

log_file = open("error.log","r")
print log_file.read()
```